# No option to create pull request from Upsource

Tags: github, jetbrains-ide, upsource

First time using Upsource and according to the [documentation](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/upsource/synchronizing-your-activities-in-github-projects.html#Pull-requests-and-merges) we should have an option to create pull requests from it. However, not sure why it would not appear? I see the branch fine from github but the PR dropdown is not there.

This is what I see:
[image]

But looking for this instead:
[image]

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems I needed to be authenticated as the github user rather than the administrator. It's working now.